# cannot run azure CLI commands from Jenkins

Tags: azure, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to run some az commands from a Jenkins pipeline which (running in Windows 10) I already use in my laptop´s Jenkins, but when trying to use it on another computer (also running w10) I get this error :

```
11:12:47  powershell.exe : az : The term 'az' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the 
11:12:47  At C:\Users\User\.jenkins\workspace\playground@tmp\durable-933c3d89\powershellWrapper.ps1:3 char:1
11:12:47  + & powershell -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Comm ...
11:12:47  + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
11:12:47      + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (az : The term '...ram. Check the :String) [], RemoteException
11:12:47      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
11:12:47   
11:12:47  spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
11:12:47  At C:\Users\User\.jenkins\workspace\playground@tmp\durable-933c3d89\powershellScript.ps1:3 char:25
11:12:47  +                         az devops configure --defaults organization=h ...
11:12:47  +                         ~~
11:12:47      + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (az:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
11:12:47      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
11:12:47   
11:12:47  az : The term 'az' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the 
11:12:47  spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
11:12:47  At C:\Users\User\.jenkins\workspace\playground@tmp\durable-933c3d89\powershellScript.ps1:4 char:35
11:12:47  +                         $output = az boards work-item show --id=89609 ...
11:12:47  +                                   ~~
11:12:47      + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (az:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
11:12:47      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

However running any command from the cmd / powershell works fine. I have set the `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` command but I do not get any hint of what is going wrong

Comment: It looks like the Az CLI is simply not installed?

Comment: it is installed, I can run az commands from the cmd in the same computer

Comment: Is it a `PATH` issue? Are the right environment variables set for it to find the az executable? You could try specifying the complete path of the executable in your script or make sure the env variables are the same between your ad hoc session and the script

Comment: I just installed azure CLI in my laptop and it worked straight away without adding any variables, I am pretty sure the windows installer do that already

Comment: What about running the az.exe with full path, does that work?

Comment: hmmm I do not think there is an .exe as such. This is what I get when running where az:
C:\Users\User>where az
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\wbin\az
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\wbin\az.cmd

C:\Users\User>
But I get the same error if using the fullpath within jenkins (it works in cmd / powershell)

Comment: Jenkins nodes do not have the same path as your desktop user does. You can add it to the path in the node settings.

Comment: @smelm it is the master node, I have done it in other 2 computers without adding anything to the path node settings, but how can I do that so I can try?

Comment: in the settings for the master node, way at the bottom there should be a field for path

Comment: I did that but still does not work, it seems like it does not take any of the path variables, as I had the same issue with cppcheck, but I sorted just writting the path instead of the command, but it does not seem to work writting the az path instead the command. I wonder why I have this issue, since I run the jenkins.war from cmd with privileges, should it not take the path variables by default?

Comment: I have check in http://localhost:8080/systemInfo in the Environment variables -> Path section and I have azure cli path in there, so I do not know what is wrong...

Comment: As a final check can you echo the $PATH variable in your Jenkins script?